# MQ JMS Topic Equivalent in C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c, ibm-mq

I don't have a clear knowledge about MQ using TOPICS and I have searched in IBM documentation and I can't find the way to subscribe with C++ to a Topic. In Java I have seen that you can go to the Websphere Control Panel and you configure it there. Programmatically how is possible to do it in C++? 
In C++ I have connected to queues using the functions MQCONN, MQOPEN and to get the messages I use MQGET and MQPUT, but I think I am only connected to queues not TOPICS. 
I want too to figure it out if I have the correct idea if connect to topic is different than connect to a queue. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is advisable to use the C MQ API when programming in C++ because the C++ classes are stabilized and have not (and will not) be updated with classes for topics, as per [IBM Knowledge Center: Developing C++ applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030180_.htm)

> IBM WebSphere® MQ Version 7.0, enhancements to the IBM MQ programming interfaces are not applied to the C++ classes.

In order use a topic from the C MQ API here is a quick pseudo-code example. Please also check out the IBM supplied samples, such as `amqspuba.c` and `amqssuba.c`.

### To Publish to a topic

```
MQOD mqod  {MQOD_DEFAULT};
MQCONN...
mqod.ObjectType = MQOT_TOPIC;
mqod.Version    = MQOD_VERSION_4; /* To use ObjectString field */
mqod.ObjectString.VSPtr = argv[1];
mqod.ObjectString.VSLength = MQVS_NULL_TERMINATED;
MQOPEN(hConn,
       &mqod,
       MQOO_OUTPUT,
       &hObj,
       &CompCode, &Reason);
MQPUT....
```

### To Subscribe to a topic

```
MQSD mqsd  {MQSD_DEFAULT};
MQCONN...
mqsd.Options = MQSO_CREATE | MQSO_NON_DURABLE | MQSO_MANAGED;
mqsd.ObjectString.VSPtr = argv[1];
mqsd.ObjectString.VSLength = MQVS_NULL_TERMINATED;
MQSUB(hConn,
      &mqsd,
      &hObj,
      &hSub,
      &CompCode, &Reason);
MQGET from hObj...
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I expressed wrong my question, but you've got my point. Use the MQ developed by IBM to subscribe and publish in a topic. I couldn't find the options you gave me. Thanks Morag.

Comment: Please accept Morag's answer if it was helpful.   Morag  do you have reference to the stabilization statement from IBM for which version it happened in?  I know for example that IBM classes for Java were stabilized more recently IBM v8.0 or v9.0.

Comment: Thank you Morag, that is just the reference I was looking for!

Comment: Morag do you know if there is in significance to IBM not using the term stabilized with regard to C++?  In the case of Java the IBM KC states "IBM will make no further enhancements to the IBM MQ classes for Java and they are functionally stabilized at the level shipped in IBM MQ Version 8.0."  I have seen similar statements for other features.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc - Not sure what you're asking exactly. IBM has stated the C++ classes are stabilized too. In fact C++ was the first to be stabilized around the V7.0 time frame. Hence the first line of my answer. What makes you say that IBM are not using the term?

Comment: In the KC link it does not mention stabilize.

Comment: My recollection is that the announcement letter (perhaps the one that announced MQ V7.0) was where it stated that the C++ classes were stabilized. Certainly we used that term a lot in IBM Hursley at the time. I don't know why the term isn't used in KC, if it is used for the Java classes. Perhaps it wasn't considered a commonly used term in the V7.0 time frame, and by V8.0 it was used much more and the doc writers picked up on that.

Comment: Thank you Morag for the history.   It is interesting to know Rhett background.