# Get only MQ9 messages that belong to a group "2" in C++

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I am trying to use IBM MQ client 9 with C++. I would like to read only messages that has group id '2'. I have tried everything but it just does not work. Can someone assist please?

I tried to set groupId and flag to match on group.

### MQGET

```
gmoptions.setMatchOptions(MQMO_MATCH_GROUP_ID);
MQBYTE24 bGroupId("2");
ImqBinary _groupId;
_groupId.set(bGroupId, sizeof(bGroupId));
message.setGroupId(_groupId);
q->get(message, gmoptions);
```

### MQPUT

```
MQBYTE24 bGroupId("2");
ImqBinary _groupId;
_groupId.set(bGroupId, sizeof(bGroupId));
message.setGroupId(_groupId);
ImqPutMessageOptions pmo;
pmo.setOptions(MQPMO_LOGICAL_ORDER);
pmo.setRecordFields(MQPMRF_GROUP_ID);
q->put(message, pmo);
```

mqget should be able to get all the msgs with groupId "2" but it does not. Though it can read the msg as soon as I remove setMatchOptions.

Basically, I want to use Group Id as filter where server instance 1 will read msgs only in group1 and server instance 2 will read msgs only in group 2 and so on, instead of creating separate queues for each server instance.

May be following can help me if group id is only for batching instead of filtering though not sure how to do 'Selection using the MQSUB and MQOPEN function calls' in C++
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q022990_.htm

**Is there any C++ equivalent of MQSETMP ? I am unable to find any interface in ImqQueue or ImqObject that will let me set message property or selectionString.**

Comment: Can you browse a message that has groupId "2" with the `amqsbcg` sample program and provide the output of the `GroupId` line, it may look something like this `GroupId : X'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'`.

Comment: Normally this field is used with the queue manager is Auto segmenting messages (ex: setting message flag `MQMF_SEGMENTATION_ALLOWED`.  each unique message group of messages would have a unique group ID along with the individual messaging each having a sequence number (ex: 1, 2, 3) and an offset in the overall message, and the last message in the group will have a flag indicating it is the last message.

Comment: Application can also use it to create groups of messages.  But as you pointed out it is a 24 Byte field and you are only setting it to the byte value of the ascii character "2".

Comment: Pub sub is not supported in C++.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101776/mq-jms-topic-equivalent-in-c-c/57103936#57103936

Comment: To answer your last update see the link I  provided.   C++ classes were stabilized at v6 level and no enhancements have been done from 7.0 or later.   Message properties were added in 7.0.  You would need to use C API to use these features.  Any reason you don't respond to the comments I am leaving you?

Comment: You are right JoshMc. I came to the same conclusion. Though I have sent a support query to IBM. Lets see what they say. In the meantime, I have started developing using 'C' API.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are going about this the right way.

IBM published a Java/MQ sample program to get messages in a group called ***GetGroup.java***.  You can find it [here](https://capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html).  You can use it as a model for your C++ program.

Basically, the code retrieves a message from the queue and then checks the ***messageFlags*** field if the message is part of a group.

```
if ((myMessage.messageFlags & CMQC.MQMF_MSG_IN_GROUP) == CMQC.MQMF_MSG_IN_GROUP)
```

If the message is part of the group then the code sets the ***matchOptions*** for matching on a group and retrieves all of the messages in the group.

Note: You will probably want to add logical order to the GMO options.

```
gmo.options |= CMQC.MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER;
```

Finally, what is this?

```
pmo.setRecordFields(MQPMRF_GROUP_ID);
```

That doesn't make any sense.  You should be setting ***messageFlags*** field to ***MQMF_MSG_IN_GROUP***.

Comment: It defeats the whole purpose. I do not want to read the message at all if msg is not part of the group. What is the use of match option MQMO_MATCH_GROUP_ID if i have to read the msg and then only compare the group id? Queue will keep getting msgs in multiple groups repeatedly and I want to touch the msg if and only if it belongs to the single group "2" i am interested in.

Comment: I don't think you are using MQ Message Grouping correctly.  You should read the MQ Knowledge Center.  Each message group should have a unique id and each message group should be of a finite number (i.e. 5, 10, 20, etc.).  It sounds like you have a single queue that receives many different types of messages and you are trying to use the Group Id as some sort of filter.  Not a good idea.  Each message type/purpose should have its own queue.  Hence, you do not need to filter the messages.

Comment: In IBM MQ, messages can occur within groups to allow ordering of messages. Typically, a practical scenario would be if system A is generating messages for system B to consume in batches(groups), but System B should consume each batch of messages separately only when all messages in a batch have arrived in the queue. Also, if messages have to be processed in a sequence, then one uses grouping concept. Please explain your overall scenario.

Comment: Yes Roger is right. I am trying to use Group Id as filter where server instance 1 will read msgs only in group1 and server instance 2 will read msgs only in group 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of **SELECTORS in IBM MQ**. A message selector is a variable-length string used by an application to register its interest in only those messages that have properties that satisfy the Structured Query Language (SQL) query that the selection string represents.

A message selector is a concept that has been in the JMS specification for a long time. It
is a way of limiting the messages that are passed to an application to those that meet
certain criteria. Those criteria are based on the values of the message properties and only
the value of the message properties. It is important to understand that selection cannot be
based on any values of the message payload, only on the message property values.

In your case, the PUT application will have to put messages with populating the a certain topic string in MQMD or MQRFH2 header and using MQ Interface function calls, you should be able to pick the messages only with a certain value which in your case is GroupId value.

Below are few reference links to the concept:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q022990_.htm

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/topic/com.ibm.iea.wmq_v7/wmq/7.0/MQI/iea_330_wmqv7_API_3_Selectors.pdf    ==> Pdf gets downloaded

To understand Message Properties =>  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q022920_.htm

Comment: Is this supported in the c++ API, I did not think it was.

Comment: I went through the following link of XMS for C++ that is similar to JMS. 
 https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ia94-ibm-message-service-client-xms-cc. Using this it should be possible to do message selection based on the ia94.pdf that is present in the link that can be downloaded.

Comment: @frabar - is there any C/C++ sample for Selectors?

Comment: Is there any C++ equivalent of MQSETMP ? I am unable to find any interface in ImqQueue or ImqObject that will let me set message property or selectionString.

Comment: The other iron is to use the XMS C++ API. Or rethink why you don't want to use 2 queues.

Comment: Creating multiple queues is not feasible option since that will force us to keep creating new queues every time we want to scale it up with multiple instances. I have to stick with Websphere MQ since my organization is using it.

Comment: But that is exactly what you want.  In the world of micro services, each service should/must have its own queue to read messages from.

Comment: Is there a difference in the content/payload of the messages are sent to server instance 1 and server instance 2?  Also note that if you want someone to know that you are responding to them you need to place there name with @ in front.  For instance if I want to notify Roger that I'm responding I can put @Roger.  You as the question poster always get notified.

Comment: Can you respond to the above question?

Comment: @JoshMc Thx. I have been using @ name but not sure why it is not displaying. Though Thx for your help.

Comment: The question was: Is there a difference in the content/payload of the messages are sent to server instance 1 and server instance 2?